# Why are any of the `RuntimeApiSubsystemClient` trait methods marked `async` when its not needed?

Tags: wasm, runtime-api, subsystems, runtime-client

The trait `RuntimeApiSubsystemClient` and its implementation `DefaultSubsystemClient`

(https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/c421b87978404954dec4555895d50ef028b73cf0/polkadot/node/subsystem-types/src/runtime_client.rs#L351)

has all methods marked as `async`, even though none of the code requires it.
The implementation invokes the `runtime_api()` from the trait bound `ProvideRuntimeApi` which does not have any `async` methods. Neither do any of the other trait bounds.

The `.await` keyword is never used which makes me wonder why the `async` keyword has not been remove from the trait `RuntimeApiSubsystemClient`.

Is this a historic leftover?
I imagine the runtime-api once provided `async` interfaces, which does not seem to be the case any more. The spawned wasm instance works provides synchronous interfaces for the runtime-api, correct?

In our codebase I was able to easily remove the `async` from the trait and implemention without any problems. All tests run fine and there seems to be literally no reason the methods should be `async`.

Any input on this or background on this historic development would be appreciated.

Kind regards,

Mathis Wellmann, gensyn.ai